# Transformar decimal em minutos vb

Tags: vb.net

Bom eu sei que se eu pegar por exemplo 4,70 e transformar o ",70" em minutos, eu tenho q pegar o 0,70 ( numero apos a virgula ) e multiplicado por 60, que daria 42, em valor de horas seria 4:42

Como faço pra aplicar isso em VB? como pego o numero apos a virgula, multiplico por 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar a parte decimal do número desta forma:

```
parte_decimal = (valor - Int(valor))
```

Assim você subtrai a parte inteira, sobrando apenas a parte decimal.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, deu certo muito obrigado!


o codigo que eu usei caso alguem tenha interesse de transformar decimal para hora

Dim parte_decimal As Double
        parte_decimal = (TextBox1.Text - Int(TextBox1.Text))
        TextBox2.Text = parte_decimal * "60"
        TextBox3.Text = Int(TextBox1.Text) & ":" & TextBox2.Text & ""

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa solução seria utilizar a função de conversão para INT na sua variável. Sendo assim a diferença entre os dois (Real - Inteiro) lhe forneceria os número após a vírgula.

Exemplo:

```
Valor_Total = 4,70

valor_decimal = (Valor_Total - Int(Valor_Total))
total_minutos = valor_decimal * 60

MessageBox.Show ("Total de minutos: " + (Int(Valor_Total)ToString() + ":" + total_minutos.ToString())
```

> > Total de Minutos: 4:42

Bom esse é apenas uma solução, mas tem muitas outras disponiveis!